# Dropwizard error messages from Jersey

Tags: error-handling, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm getting the below log output. I guess drop wizard is trying to error but the Jersey JAX-RS implementation it uses doesn't know how to format the error? How can I view it?

```
ERROR [2014-10-01 08:08:55,875] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.ErrorMessage, and Java type class io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.ErrorMessage, and MIME media type text/plain was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
text/plain ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
```

FWIW the method signature I'm hitting is:

```
@POST
@UnitOfWork
@Path("/update")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String updateResults(ResultsUpdate results) {...}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a serialiszer for ErrorMessage. If you use eclipse Strg+Shift+T and search for "JsonProcessingExceptionMapper". This Exception mapper wants to build response with entity ErrorMessage, but you have no mapper for this.

You have two options:

1. Remove this exception mapper and add your custom exception mapper
   with no entity
2. You create a message body writer.

Option 1:
add this method in your run():

```
private void removeDefaultExceptionMappers(boolean deleteDefault,Environment environment)
{
    if(deleteDefault){
        ResourceConfig jrConfig = environment.jersey().getResourceConfig();
        Set<Object> dwSingletons = jrConfig.getSingletons();
        List<Object> singletonsToRemove = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (Object singletons : dwSingletons) {
            if (singletons instanceof ExceptionMapper && !singletons.getClass().getName().contains("DropwizardResourceConfig")) {
                singletonsToRemove.add(singletons);
            }
        }

        for (Object singletons : singletonsToRemove) {
            LOG.info("Deleting this ExceptionMapper: " + singletons.getClass().getName());
            jrConfig.getSingletons().remove(singletons);
        }
    }
}
```

This removes all exeption mappers added by default in DW. Now you can add all exeption mappers you really want. In my case:

```
    environment.jersey().register(new ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper());
    environment.jersey().register(new CustomJsonProcessingExceptionMapper());
    environment.jersey().register(new EarlyEofExceptionMapper());
```

Now write your own custom CustomJsonProcessingExceptionMapper without entity:

```
@Provider
public class CustomJsonProcessingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonProcessingException> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJsonProcessingExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonProcessingException exception) {
        /*
         * If the error is in the JSON generation, it's a server error.
         */
        if (exception instanceof JsonGenerationException) {
            LOG.warn("Error generating JSON", exception);
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }

        final String message = exception.getOriginalMessage();

        /*
         * If we can't deserialize the JSON because someone forgot a no-arg constructor, it's a
         * server error and we should inform the developer.
         */
        if (message.startsWith("No suitable constructor found")) {
            LOG.error("Unable to deserialize the specific type", exception);
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }

        /*
         * Otherwise, it's those pesky users.
         */
        LOG.debug("Unable to process JSON (those pesky users...)", exception);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                       .build();
    }

}
```

Option 2:
You create an serializer/message body writer for ErrorMessage. To do so try this:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class ErrorMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<ErrorMessage> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorMessageBodyWriter.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return ValidationErrorMessage.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(
        ErrorMessage t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(
        ErrorMessage t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {       
        String message = t.getMessage();        
        entityStream.write(message.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        LOG.info(message);
    }

}
```

Add in your run():

```
// Serializer
environment.jersey().register(new ErrorMessageBodyWriter());
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: option 2 worked for me except that in the isWriteable() method I had to change it to `return type == ErrorMessage.class;`

Answer (score 6):

Just need to specify these headers for your resource so that dropwizard understands which error message builder to use for the response:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: I was getting the exact same error and this fixed it. What did you do to fix your issue? Writing custom exception mapper or error message body writer doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3):

Dropwizard will log the underlying error at DEBUG level, so you can turn that on in your logging config to see the cause here:

```
io.dropwizard.jersey.jackson.JsonProcessingExceptionMapper: DEBUG
```

Comment: That's the best, simplest and most durable answer. In your config.yml file (or whatever the name), under "logging:", add the line above. No other solution currently on this page was working properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is daft, but I clicked that dropwizard runs from a main class so you can just put a breakpoint in ErrorMessage and run it within (e.g.) Eclipse.

Incidentally the underlying error in this case was:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this a couple of times recently and so submitted a (now accepted) pull request to log the underlying error at warn rather than debug.

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commit/ebdfcb47a030730233cf0984aadae155ec138ff3

Comment: Looks like it got reverted: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commit/9f2df976b2b1fda7dfb19fbdfd0c670914791f8a

Was this because there is a preferred alternative?

Comment: No idea. Helpfully no explanation on the commit.